# How to avoid conflicts in branch dependent files in mercurial branches?

Tags: maven, mercurial, merge, gradle, dependency-management

My team uses HG to develop three different environments (each is its own branch):

- Release (what is running operationally)
- QA (what we're testing)
- Dev (what we're developing)

When QA is done with a batch of changes, we merge QA onto Release. Then we merge Dev onto QA. Occasionally a hotfix is required in Release which is committed directly into Release. Then Release is merged onto QA, and QA onto Dev.

This workflow has worked really well, except for one detail. Our build system references different Maven dependencies on each branch. So, for example, on QA our build file might look like this:

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    // This dependency shouldn't ever change during a merge.
    compile 'internal.lib:lib-qa:1.0'
}
```

and on release it might look like this:

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    // This dependency shouldn't ever change during a merge.
    compile 'internal.lib:lib-release:1.0'
}
```

When I do any sort of merge (hotfix or normal), mercurial changes the line that looks like this:

```
    compile 'internal.lib:lib-release:1.0'
```

I can manually revert this change before committing my merge, but I want to avoid this step because I'll eventually forget and break Release. Is there some practice or trick that can make this step unneeded?

The best I've come up with so far is to have my build check the branch and then dynamically determine the dependency to use, but that's not satisfying as it makes my build depend on HG (and I've had issues with the Gradle Eclipse plugin not working correctly when HG is required by Gradle).

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what the problem is with Gradle Eclipse and dynamically choosing dependencies based on querying version control, but I think it should be solvable. Some other approaches:

- Write a validation task that gets run (and queries version control) only at certain times, for example at the start of a release or after you've done the merge.
- Encode the branch type in the build script (for example as part of the version number); then you only need to get one line right in the merge (and it's always the same line).
- Inject the branch type from outside (defaulting to dev), and configure CI builds accordingly.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think the Eclipse issue had to do with having HG on the path. I can't be sure though.